# How to connect ionic app with a static ip and port number?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

i am a little bit confused on how to establish a connection of my ionic app and a static ip and port number suggest me some ideas to solve this. I am new for Stack Overflow and excited for reply.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: newbie tip : to make a good question here , put your code in the question :)

Comment: no code = can't resolve

Comment: Do you mean you want to host it somewhere ?

Comment: I actually want to send a message to ip address. similar to socket communication @ Thang PQ